# Can I run 2 threads same time and set one Result on java?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I want create 2 threads and run them both at the same time. I want put condition that if the first thread answer data null or empty I want set the other thread response (it can be null or empty I don't need put restriction). How can I do it, any suggestions? I want it to do in Spring Framework.

Comment: It is not clear to me, what you try to achieve and especially what it has to do with Spring. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2314575/9107502) answer will help you.

Comment: I want do it in Spring thats why I especially tagged Spring, I want to achieve that there are two feign client calling in one controller and I want it call 2 feign clients "same " time with Threads and after that if first Thread have response set it to response , if not second Thread answer will set to response.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but addressing the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75029179/2711488

Answer (score 0):

You could set an environment variable and if not a global variable maybe stuff into a control file that each thread could read. Or even a data base entry.

Comment: I call the feign client for getting data . I want call "same" time them and put condition if the first Thread have no data set the other Thread answer .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you could try CompletableFuture, e.g.

```
CompletableFuture<String> future1  
  = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> firstApi());
CompletableFuture<String> future2  
  = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> secondApi());

CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture 
  = CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2);

// wait for completion
combinedFuture.get();

// check and return results, e.g.
String result1 = future1.get();
if(null == result1) {
  return future2.get();
}
return result1;
```

https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture